# Имитация клика в определённой позиции в свёрнутом окне Python

Tags: python

Возможна ли имитация клика в определённой позиции в свёрнутом окне, к примеру у меня есть игра в которой нужно нажать на элемент находящийся по определённым координатам не разворачивая игру.

это скрипт для скриншотов

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image


def screenshot():
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'SС')
    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    w = right - left
    h = bot - top

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 3)

    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGB',
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
        bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

    im.save("SC_Scr/SC_main.jpeg")
```

это скрипт для кликов

```
import ctypes
from SC_Screenshoter import screenshot


MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004
WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201
WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202
WM_KEYUP = 0x0100
BACKSPACE_VIRTUAL_CODE = 0x08


def click():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(
        window_handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(
        window_handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0)
    screenshot()


window_handle = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(None, 'SC')
click()
```

Comment: ¿Каким образом? Если программа неактивна, откуда она возьмет данные о нажатии?

Comment: @Глеб неактивна в каком плане, приложение открыто но свёрнуто в панель задач, по моей логике если можно сделать скриншот игры не раскрывая её через ctypes то возможно есть способ имитации клика в определённой позиции в игре

Comment: @Глеб через дескриптор окна например?

Comment: @Глеб а так же можно имитировать к примеру простое нажатие мыши или клавиши через ctypes но я ни где не нашёл как это сделать в определённой позиции

Comment: @ghostiki покажите что есть, подумаем вместе.

Comment: @Amgarak у меня не особо есть что-то для примера, имеется только скрипт на скриншот игры и нажатие ЛКМ без раcкрытия самой игры, я добавлю в пост

Comment: @ghostiki не пробовали посылать также позицию курсора?

Comment: @Amgarak я не могу нигде найти нормальной документации с примерами, по этому не особо понимаю где какие значения отвечают за позицию курсора.

Comment: @ghostiki lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lParam)

Comment: @Amgarak спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ghostiki могу оформить как ответ, если примите;)

Comment: @Amgarak да, конечно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

#Вместо SendMessage можно использовать PostMessage, тогда сообщение поставится в очередь и не будет ждать пока окно обработает нажатие/смещение курсора.

win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lParam)
```